# Spring Security authentication provider not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring 4.0.9 and would like to integrate with Spring Security 4.0.4. I configured my Spring web project with the following configuration:

> **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/app-config.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <!-- Spring Security -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> **app-config.xml**

```
....
<task:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
....
```

> **security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="customAuthenticationManager">
        <headers>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </headers>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/app/Login/" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/app/Login/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/app/Login/" default-target-url="/"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    </http>

     <!-- print debug log -->
    <debug/>

    <authentication-manager alias="customAuthenticationManager" id="customAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.example.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

All redirection to unauthorized URLs is working correctly (i.e. it can redirect to login page `/app/Login/`). However, when I tried to login, it will not load into my `CustomAuthenticationProvider`. It seems that it totally ignored my authentication provider.

> **CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Test Provider");
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = auth.getName();
    String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();
    System.out.println(name +" "+ password);
    ...
}
@Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
       return authentication.equals(
         UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
   }
```

Below is the Login JSP page I used to submit the Login request. I have set the parameter username and password already, and let the action be empty. As I know we can leave it blank so that Spring Security will handle the POST request using AuthenticationProvider. I tried setting breakpoint in the Class or printing log in the authenticate() method but nothing happened.

> **login.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" id="form1" commandName="formVO">
<table width="600px" border="0" class="noGridTable" align="center">
    <tr style="height: 80px">
        <td class="message">User ID:</td>
        <td>
                <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="normalInput" style="width:320px"
                    required/>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="message">Password:</td>
        <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" style="width:320px" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 100px">
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input  name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the Spring Security debug log when I submit the POST request:

```
2017-01-27 10:00:55,052 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] [Spring Security Debugger] [INFO] - 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/app/Login/':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@22b79260

servletPath:/app
pathInfo:/Login/
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 81
cache-control: max-age=0
origin: http://localhost:8080
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
referer: http://localhost:8080/testapp/app/Login/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6
cookie: JSESSIONID=6F6A74E4DDCE967BFBFDC521AF5AFEB8
dnt: 1


Security filter chain: [
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: yes, as the app-config.xml is too long so I just added portion of the xml

Comment: Thanks, I am using LOG4J2 
I tried with the logger `<Logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"
   additivity="true">
   <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </Logger>`
but no log can be logged, I find that it is because I cannot enable the debug mode with the above config. Could you advise ?

Comment: Thanks Dur, finally I figured out what is the problem. It is a silly mistake. The form submission URL should be configured as below to trigger the authentication.
`<c:url value="/login" var="secureUrl"/>
 <form:form method="POST" id="form1" commandName="formVO" action="${secureUrl}">`